# manually setting execute() to true pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my project I have a select query where I select database entries after I select data from the database, I will then insert another set of data into the same database.
before inserting I have this line

```
//select is above this line
$stmt->execute();//where $stmt->execute() is the execute for select

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
   //manipulate selected data here
   $stmt1->execute(); //manipualte the selected data here 
}else{
   $stmt1->execute() = true 
}

if($stmt1->execute()){
//insert data here
}
```

What I want to do here is after selecting the data I want to manipulate the files. In the instant that there are no data to manipulate meaning `rowcount = 0` I still want to set the execute to true so that I can then insert data. But in my else I have error saying `Can't use method return value in write context in` in the line `$stmt1->execute() = true`.

How can I manually set the `$stmt1->execute() = true`

Comment: `$stmt1->execute() = true` What should this do??

Comment: set the execute to true so that the condition `if($stmt1->execute())` be fullfilled so that it will do inside the if statement.

Comment: The result of `execute()` returns `true` or `false` you don't set it.

Comment: You can't `execute()` is a function.. I think your code logic is the problem here

Comment: yeah thank you for clarification i will find a different way then happy coding

Comment: i declared `$stmt1_ = true` after execute and in else i also have `$stmt1_ = true` then in if `if($stmt1_)` any drawback on this solution? @Rizier123

Comment: @Pekka It is a possible solution, I maybe would first use the return value of `execute()`, which you the assign to `$stmt1_`. E.g. `$stmt1_ = $stmt->execute();` And if the rowCount is under 1 you can set it still to true.

Comment: @Rizier123 i see inside if i dont need to have `$stmt1_ = true` i just need to have `$stmt1_ = $stmt->execute();` it will return true anyway and in else i just have `$stmt1_ = true` i appreciate the suggestion mate happy coding

Comment: just a thought is there a chance that after update `execute()` will `return false`?

Comment: @Pekka If the update failed.

Comment: You can't tell a function what it's return value is. What next? `1 = 0`?

Comment: @tadman that is why i am asking i am not answering lol